# making a Tabbar controller rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application where a user can login or signup. If a user is logged in, I want to present a viewcontroller but the challenge I have now is that the view controller is in a `Tabbar` controller. How do I navigate to the Tabbar controller.

```
func goToMainPageVC () {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainPageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.PAGE_VC)
        window?.rootViewController = mainPageVC

    }
```

this is my code but this only presents the viewcontroller without the navigationItems or Tabbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the identifier to the tabBarController not to it's main vc

```
let tab = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"tab") as! UITabBarController
window?.rootViewController = tab
```

Comment: did you set the identifier for the tab ?? also is it linked to it's vcs in IB ?

Comment: do you work with RxSwift? or reactive programming in general?